# How to open a WebSocket connection asynchronously in an RCP application?

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, eclipse-rcp

I need to retrieve data through **WebSocket** and then display them in a table view in my RCP application. My first thought was to open the connection in my part code(say I have a class called `ListPart`), and the code is as following

````
public class Listpart{

  @PostConstruct
  public void createControls(Composite parent){
    //I need to open connection first
    WebsocketUtil.openConnection();

    //some other ```

    ```

  }
}
````

However this is absolutely not going to work, because `WebsocketUtil.openConnection()` will block following statements. After I check the [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJobs/article.html#tutorial-using-eclipse-jobs) from vogella's website, I'm still confusing, it seems there is no sample code fits my need. So how could I start a thread to open the **WebSocket** connection when my RCP application start and without blocking the GUI thread. Can anyone shed a light on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Open Connection(RCP) please refer the Apache Httpclient
Below are some useful links by referring them, you can understand it better:

http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/ApacheHttpClient/article.html

Comment: To make sure we are on the same page, `WebsocketUtil.openConnection()` is a method I implemented, and I want to it running in the background and whenever there is any update through the connection I will update the table view. I don't think I'm going to use Apache Httpclient.